# SQL Server perfomance tuning - Union tables having 1.5 million rows of data

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure which unions two tables each with 1.5M rows of data. Created a fulltext index for the default search field (`VARCHAR(255)`) and a non-clustered index covering column names in select/where clause.

Also pagination is applied and fetching only the necessary columns from both 
tables.

`UNION` is used as I want distinct records after combining the table.

The response time of the query varies from 3 seconds to more than a minute. When the filter text contains just two characters it is too slow, still fetches values faster when repeating the execution.

```
DECLARE @start INT, @length INT, @searchQuery VARCHAR(100) --Param
DECLARE @sortQuery VARCHAR(100)
SET @sortQuery = @searchQuery;
SET @searchQuery = ('"' + @searchQuery + '*"');

SELECT temp2.*
                , t3.Name AS CountryName
                , t5.Name AS CityName
                , t4.Name AS StateProvinceName
                , t4.Code AS StateProvinceCode      
         FROM
                (SELECT temp1.* FROM
                    (SELECT ID
                            , Name
                            , ISNULL(Address1, '') AS AddressLine1
                            , ISNULL(Address2, '') AS AddressLine2
                            , ISNULL(CityID, 0) AS CityID
                            , ISNULL(CountryID, 0) AS CountryID
                            , ISNULL(StateProvinceID, 0) AS StateProvinceID
                            , ISNULL(PostalCode, '') AS PostalCode
                    FROM Table1
                    WHERE Deleted= 0 AND CONTAINS(Name, @searchQuery)

                    UNION

                    SELECT t2.EmployerID AS ID
                            , t2.DivisionName AS Name
                            , t2.Address1 AS AddressLine1
                            , t2.Address2 AS AddressLine2
                            , t2.CityID AS CityID
                            , t2.CountryID AS CountryID
                            , t2.StateProvinceID AS StateProvinceID
                            , t2.PostalCode AS PostalCode
                    FROM Table2 t2
                    JOIN Employer t1 ON t2.EmployerID = t1.ID
                    WHERE t2.Deleted= 0 AND t2.DivisionName IS NOT NULL AND t2.DivisionName <> '' 
                            AND t1.Deleted = 0 AND t2.CountryID IS NOT NULL AND t2.Address1 IS NOT NULL AND t2.Address2 IS NOT NULL  
                            AND CONTAINS(t2.DivisionName, @searchQuery)
                    )   temp1
            ORDER BY (CASE WHEN temp1.Name LIKE @sortQuery +'%' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END) DESC, temp1.Name                                 
            OFFSET @start ROWS
            FETCH NEXT @length ROWS ONLY
            )   temp2

         JOIN Table3 t3 ON C.ID = temp2.CountryID
         JOIN Table4 t4 ON S.ID = temp2.StateProvinceID
         JOIN Table5 t5 ON Ct.ID = temp2.CityID
        ORDER BY temp2.Name
```

[image]

Comment: Is that index used? Do you see it in your query plan? How does your "pagination" work? Are you storing all filtered rows in temp table?

Comment: Sounds like maybe a parameter sniffing issue or the cached query plan for that stored procedure is not optimized.

Comment: Have you tried UNION ALL instead of UNION?  UNION gets rid of duplicate records, while UNION ALL just slaps them together.

Comment: Is data from these tables often changed? It is also useful to know the schema and the field(s) used in searches.

Comment: Hello Ivan, Im using Full-Text Index and a non-clustered index, including the selected fields. Pagination is achieved using "OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY". I am not using temp tables but using inner query to filter required rows and then making the other joins to fetch more info. Query return 12 fields in final resultset.

Comment: Rono- I got to fetch unique records comparing eight fields. I tried using UNION ALL but then it was slow in the outer query where I try to fetch distinct records.

Comment: Alexei - Data manipulation to these tables happen often.

Comment: If it was me, I'd get the datasets down to their smallest size after all the filters, in their own temporary tables and then UNION and sort them.  Your pagination is suspect due to the ordering that needs to take place just to make it work.  Paste up the execution plan or a couple with different values and we can stop guessing at what's wrong.